# Quick update with laravel 4 eloquent and javascript

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

im making a laravel 4 app where all the users can add a new movie.

The movies are stored in a database with normal values like:

-Name
-Year
-rating
-votes

etc...

And to avoid the spam at adding movies i made a confirmed boolean field, each time a user adds a movie the confirmed value is false, and the staff of the page will read the movie info and decide to confir or not.

The movie will only display to staff if the confirmed it's false and there are also 2 buttons at the movie accept & cancel.

What i need it's a jquery or javascript code that when i click one of the buttons without reloading the page it updates the confirmed field in the movie table.

I tried it but i couldn't make it work and i think that was not the bets practice please help.

Comment: Please post your code here, then only we can solve your problem.

Comment: I dont have one i erased it, colud someone at least tell me which it's the best practice to try it.

Comment: You can use jquery ajax on each button click which should pass the entry id.

Comment: You have to specify something from your code.model name, controller, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ajax.

Here is a little example:

```
<button onClick='ajaxRequest(\"video_id=<? echo $video_id; ?>\"'>Confirm</button>
function ajaxRequest(data)
{
    var url = "allow_video.php";
    var method = 'POST';
    var async = true;
    var xmlHttpRequst = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlHttpRequst = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlHttpRequst = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if(xmlHttpRequst != false){
        xmlHttpRequst.open(method, url, async);
        xmlHttpRequst.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttpRequst.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xmlHttpRequst.readyState == 4){
                if (xmlHttpRequst.status == 200){
                    alert("Video posted");
                }
            }
        }
        xmlHttpRequst.send(data);
    }
}
```

In allow_video.php

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['video_id'])){
    //update confirm field
}
?>
```

PS: You must add some session verification un allow_video.php with admin permissions or any user could confirm any video knowing the video_id or using brute force.

Comment: jmm I saw the php tag so I wrote the code, idk what laravel 4 is :/

Comment: This will work i wil make to laravel 4 if some problem i will ask thanks.

if someone could help me to adapt it to laravel 4 it will be great to.